# Amplifying pulse signal (0.1 .. 0.5V) to Arduino digital input

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, sensor, signal

How this can be so difficult (to me :-). The incoming sensor signal rests close to 0 Volts and gives ~ 0.5V pulses, which needs to be read by Arduino digital input (interrupts).

So far, what I have tried:

- 0.5Volts is just under optocoupler to function, that would have been easy.
- Reading directly this small signal to Analog input. OK, but timing is not enough accurate. So, definitely want to use Arduino digital interrupt.

When sensor sends 0.5V pulse -> 5V to arduino digital input HIGH state. If sensor signal goes under 0.2V -> Arduino digital input to LOW state.

OK, OP amps perhaps, but how? Have tried to simulate, without getting right things around suitable op amp.

- I have single DC supply +5Volt to drive things.
- I would like to keep component amount small, tiny package.

Comment: Why not use the analog comparator with an appropriate reference?

Comment: An analog comparator is nice, but if your input is a bit noisy, a Schmidt trigger might be set to only trigger below 0.2V and above 0.3V. [EEVblog #941 - Schmitt Trigger Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ht48vv0rQYk)

Answer (score 6):

Most ATMega ICs have a built an analogue comparator (AC) module already, so there is little need to use external circuitry unless you want control over the hysteresis.

For an Arduino Uno, the AC pins are PD6 and PD7 (digital pin 6 and digital pin 7 in "Arduino" speak). To PD6 (AIN0) you would connect a DC reference voltage of where you want your threshold to be (in your case ~0.3V), and to PD7 (AIN1) you connect your input pulse signal.

If you want to be able to measure more than one signal (albeit one at a time), you can use any of the analogue input pins (A0 through A5) instead of PD7. The ADC multiplexer output inside the MCU can be routed through to the analogue comparator. However, be aware that the ADC cannot be used simultaneously with the analogue comparator if using the multiplexer as the input source.

---

For the ATMega32U4 on a Pololu Micro as per your comment, things are a tiny bit different. These do still have an analogue comparator, however they don't have an AIN1 pin. Instead you must use the ADC Mux as the source for your signal, so that means you can feed the pulse signal into any of the A0 through A5 pins on the micro board.

For the DC reference, AIN0, that is on PE6 which corresponds to digital pin 7.

---

For your reference DC signal, you can simply use a pair of resistors as a voltage divider, and possibly also a small (~100nF) decoupling capacitor to smooth out noise.

To read whether the signal is high or low, you can then either check the `ACO` bit of the `ACSR` register, or you can set up an interrupt service routine for the `ANALOG_COMP_vect` interrupt vector.

If you are interested in timing your signal, the `ACO` bit can also be internally routed directly to the input capture register of Timer 1, so you can timestamp transitions of the signal.

Comment: Oh yeah. Now we are talking. But, I happen to have now 32U4 micro arduino (pololu). Hope it's not too much different from 'standard' arduino Uno, when accessing directly to registers. This micro-arduino has two Analog inputs (free to use in my case). Definitely I give this a shot first, before fooling around with semi-conductors.

Comment: @jengstronotarealsurname For that board, you should use D7 for the DC reference voltage, and any of the analogue A0 through A5 pins for the pulse in signal. However you can't use the ADC at the same time as using the analogue comparator for this device.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKtmlD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. This analog comparator with a 0.25 V reference will give an output high when the input exceeds the reference.*

Things to watch:

- You want a comparator that will operate on a 5 V supply.
- Make sure the inputs work down very close to 0 V.
- Many have open-collector outputs and require a pull-up. You may be able to use the micro's internal pull-up instead of R3.
- I haven't shown a decoupling capacitor on the 5 V supply. You need one.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the "Arduino" or more precisely the atmega mcu series has a comparator built in. So you don't even need an external one.

Comment: @Mike It seems we thought the same thing at the same time :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple circuit that can achieve what you want with just a few cheap components. The input from your sensor will connect to the emitter terminal of the NPN transistor. The output at the collector will connect to the digital input of the MCU board. The 5V to power the circuit can also come from the MCU board.

[image]

Comment: This is looks so interesting, need to try it with some electronics simulation sw. "Pushing" signal upwards to emitter, and somehow overcoming the issue with under 0.7V base-emitter :-) Is this circuit somehow affecting input source anyway. Input signal is "stolen/parallel" from original sensor application.

Comment: This circuit does require the sensor source signal to sink the NPN emitter current when the sensor output is low. As designed that current is quite low.

Comment: If that is too much current then you have to resort to the comp

Comment: Ator type circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there... but not. I found this library, so I dont have to start bit masking those registers (lazy, yes indeed)

```
#include "analogComp.h"
// Pololu ASTAR a32u4
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  analogComparator.setOn(AIN0, A1); // AIN0 is on D7. As a reference voltage
  analogComparator.enableInterrupt(speedSensorInterrupt);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
   delay (1000);
   Serial.println(".");
}

void speedSensorInterrupt()
{
   Serial.println("Comparator Interrupt between A1<->D7!");
}
```

So, D7 is right (AIN0), at least it makes effect. Due that interrupt is raised when going over ~0.8V on that input. However A1 (signal input) voltage level, does not make any effect when interrupt is raised. Hmm, what could be the issue?

Comment: Moved this to more correct forum, Arduino (sw) side. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/53399/a32u4-pololu-astar-trying-to-use-analog-comparator-interrupt